# Use awk to remove unwanted spaces

Tags: shell, awk

I have the following piece of code:

```
awk_cmd='{ if ($4 == '"$1"') { printf $0 } }'
printf "$(date +%s)$EPM_DB_SEP" >> "$EPM_RUN_DIR/$2.pid"
ps -e -o user,group,comm,pid,ppid,pgid,etime,nice,rgroup,ruser,time,tty,vsz,stat,rss,args |\
    awk "$awk_cmd" | sed 's/  */ /g' >> "$EPM_RUN_DIR/$2.pid"
```

Can I modify $awk_cmd to avoid using sed later to remove the unwanted spaces?

The awk version implied is the one coming with BusyBox v1.26.2

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you. Both the script in your question and the script in your answer are riddled with problems. Also explain why you're trying to store an awk script in a variable (vs, say, defining a shell function to call awk if you need a reusable awk script) as that just makes things more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably what you want:

```
function awk_cmd { awk -v pid="$1" -v ORS= '$4 == pid{$1=$1; print}'; }
printf "$(date +%s)$EPM_DB_SEP" >> "$EPM_RUN_DIR/$2.pid"
ps -e -o user,group,comm,pid,ppid,pgid,etime,nice,rgroup,ruser,time,tty,vsz,stat,rss,args |
    awk_cmd "$1" >> "$EPM_RUN_DIR/$2.pid"
```

but without sample input/output it's an untested guess.

Answer (score 0):

I’m adding another answer as I can’t edit the first one (I don’t understand why and contacted the site about that…). I’m giving more context and took into account Ed Morton’s comment. Also put "pid" in the first column.

```
filter_pid() { awk -v pid="$1" -v ORS= '$1 == pid{$1=$1; print}'; }

ps_store_current_info() {
    printf "$(date +%s)$EPM_DB_SEP" >> "$EPM_RUN_DIR/$2.pid"
    ps -e -o pid,ppid,user,group,comm,pgid,etime,nice,rgroup,ruser,time,tty,vsz,stat,rss,args |\
    filter_pid $1 >> "$EPM_RUN_DIR/$2.pid"
    printf "\n" >> "$EPM_RUN_DIR/$2.pid"
}
```

$EPM_DB_SEP equals `|` and $EPM_RUN_DIR points to a directory.

I well understand that doing this is not very clever because I won’t be able to later use the space as my (sub)field-separator but that’s really is another problem…

Answer (score -1):

Very simple…

```
awk_cmd='{ if ($4 == '"$1"') { gsub("  *"," ",$0); printf $0 } }'
printf "$(date +%s)$EPM_DB_SEP" >> "$EPM_RUN_DIR/$2.pid"
ps -e -o user,group,comm,pid,ppid,pgid,etime,nice,rgroup,ruser,time,tty,vsz,stat,rss,args |\
    awk "$awk_cmd" >> "$EPM_RUN_DIR/$2.pid"
```

Comment: There are at least 5 problems on the first line of that script alone. Don't do it.

Comment: Thx for your code, it works. I wasn’t aware of the ORS variable in awk. What difference does it make between using a function or a variable in this case, except readibility?

I’m curious about the 5 problems you’re thinking about…

I already noticed one: some of my fields may contain spaces, in particular the "comm" value, and then it won’t work as expected (nor your version). I should probably put the "pid" value in the first column to handle the case.

What are the other four?

Comment: 1) awk is `condition { action }` statements, puting the condition inside the action doesn't make sense, 2) allowing a shell variable to expand to become part of an awk script leads to obscure failures based on that variables value (see Q24 in the comp.unix.shell FAQ), 3) using $0 as the only arg to printf means it's treated as the format string so if $0 contains `%s` or any other printf formatting chars it'll fail obscurely, 4) $0 is the default for gsub(), no need to write it, 5) the first arg for gsub() is a regexp not a string so should be inside regexp `/.../`, not string delimters `"..."`

Comment: Oh, and wrt using a function rather than defining a string as the awk script, defining a string is harder to get the quoting and escaping etc. right because not only are you fighting against the shell when you define the string, you then need to let it expand withing double quotes ahen you're trying to get awk to use it so the shell gets yet **another** chance to do globbing, word, splitting, filename expansion, etc. - it's extremely fragile and difficult to get right.